# Deploying Django app using passenger

Tags: django, passenger, dreamhost

I can get through everything on their wiki - and then I'm lost. http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django

I have a blank Django template, and whenever I try to change anything I get a 500 internal server error.

I have completely developed my django app locally and just want to host it online - figured it would be easy but am slowly learning that it is not.

I upload my app "videos" to this directory and then put it into the installed apps and ran "python manage.py syncdb", which finds no fixtures (which I Found odd).

From there, it just gets an internal server error.

Here is the error I am getting: http://tweettune.com/ and here is the error log:

```
[Wed Aug 24 01:49:15 2011] [error] [client 66.212.30.122] Premature end of script headers:
[Wed Aug 24 01:49:15 2011] [error] [client 66.212.30.122] Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html
[Wed Aug 24 08:16:40 2011] [error] [client 99.229.160.94] Premature end of script headers:
[Wed Aug 24 08:16:41 2011] [error] [client 99.229.160.94] Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html
[Wed Aug 24 08:21:38 2011] [error] [client 99.229.160.94] Premature end of script headers:
[Wed Aug 24 08:21:38 2011] [error] [client 99.229.160.94] Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html
[Wed Aug 24 08:27:41 2011] [error] [client 99.229.160.94] Premature end of script headers:
[Wed Aug 24 08:27:41 2011] [error] [client 99.229.160.94] Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html
```

I've been trying for 6 hours now and can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I suppose I just don't understand how to deploy an application at all - my thought process now is take my locally hosted app and replace all the files in the default django template online. I don't see why this should not work but it's not. I tried the "hello world app" example by using this code in my passenger_wdgi file and it works...

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return ["Hello, world!"]
```

Any direction would be helpful.

**EDIT:** Here are the contents of my passenger_wsgi.py file which may be helpful (although it is automatically generated by dreamhost...so figured it would be correct).

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "sotd.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
project_path='/home/tweettune.com/sotd/'
sys.path.insert(1, project_path)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by my config files? The passenger_wsgi.py contents? Please excuse my ignorance on this subject - first time trying to deploy a project.

Comment: I think you have got your paths wrong. Navigate to your project directory in the shell, and use `pwd` to print the full name of that directory.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.
The solution was to add the folder of my application in the wsgi_passenger.py

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'include your apps folder here'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "cpc.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

This link was very useful to me:
http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-128918.html

Answer (score 7):

If using django>1.7 replace two last line with

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know exactly what you're doing wrong without seeing your setup. I followed the instructions, and it wasn't that hard.

One thing you can do to debug your application is to run through manage.py. It won't be able to bind to a socket (and if it does, it will get autokilled after a few minutes), but that will at least show if there are other problems that prevent your app from running.

One other thing to note: the file is called `passenger_wsgi.py`, and should live in your site root. For example, I have `~/testing.tustincommercial.com/passenger_wsgi.py`, and all of my project code lives under `~/testing.tustincommercial.com/oneclickcos`. My static content lives under `~/testing.tustincommercial.com/public`.

It can help to have some error-handling middleware installed, so that errors don't propagate all the way to passenger, thus triggering a 500 error.

My `wsgi_passenger.py` is:

```
import sys, os, re
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

#add all installed eggs to path
for x in ['/home/marcintustin/django/'+x for x in os.listdir('/home/marcintustin/django/') if re.search('egg$', x)]:
    sys.path.insert(0,x)

sys.path.insert(0,'/home/marcintustin/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/marcintustin/django/Django-1.3')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/marcintustin/django/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.5.egg')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/marcintustin/django/South-0.7.3-py2.5.egg')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/marcintustin/django/Werkzeug-0.6.2-py2.5.egg')

myapp_directory = cwd + '/oneclickcos'
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
sys.path.insert(0,myapp_directory)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "oneclickcos.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#from paste.exceptions.errormiddleware import ErrorMiddleware
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
from django.core.servers.basehttp import run, AdminMediaHandler, WSGIServerException

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
handler = AdminMediaHandler(application, '/home/marcintustin/testing.tustincommercial.com/public/static/admin')
application = DebuggedApplication(handler, evalex=True)
```

This does a bunch of stuff, most of which isn't strictly necessary - all of the stuff at the top is to make sure that the libraries I've installed are available. The stuff at the bottom installs middleware. You're probably better off with `paste.exceptions.errormiddleware.ErrorMiddleware`, unless the werkzeug debugger works for you (it won't work for me on Dreamhost).

**Edit:** I think your config is wrong. Please go the directory which holds your project, and use `pwd` to get the full path. I think you will find you have not got your paths right.

Comment: I suppose I have a question then. Would I expect to see the normal django debug errors if there was an issue with my setup or will it just turn back a 500 server error?

Comment: A 500 error could be caused either by exceptions from your code propagating all the way to the top, or by a problem with your configuration. The point of installing the middleware is to catch and display exceptions coming out of your code. So, bad configuration will cause a 500 error, but it is not the only possible source.

Comment: PWD response - /home/brandonmattalo/tweettune.com
and my django project itself is /home/brandonmattalo/tweettune.com/sotd

Comment: Sorry, when you say config what would you be referring to so that I can look into it a bit more. And just a question so I can help debug it myself as well - in a django app if it threw up a normal django exception (For example template not found, or python syntax error) would I expect to see this when running it on dreamhost (assuming settings.py has Debug=True)? OR does it just go to this 500 error.

Comment: Hmm I seem to now be getting django errors after I changed one small thing in my settings installed apps <sitename>.<app> as opposed to just <app> but now I have a bunch more (although more familiar errors) to work though. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: Did you fix your project path?

Comment: Yes I did it worked perfectly, sorry meant to come back here and thank you. if you want to check out the finished project [Tweet Tune](http://www.tweettune.com) - thanks again for the help. The main problem ended up being that on my dev server I could do a "from video.models import Video" However on the actual server I had to do from <project_name>.video.models import Video - and this was for all models. Not sure why since it was the same project paths but it did end up working.

Comment: Note that the default python version on dreamhost is 2.5.2. I don't know if the details of package handling have changed since that version.

Comment: I noted this as well and installed my own version using env since I had package dependencies that I required and don't have root access since I'm on a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The answers here put me in the right direction, thanks. I use virtualenv with my django app and the os.getcwd() did it for me.

```
import os, sys

#Fix for passenger
INTERP = "/var/webapps/myapp_env/bin/python"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
#

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```